# How to delete images from Excel.Worksheet in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I'm working on a C# document level customization VSTO for Excel.  In it, I will come across some worksheets that have some `Bitmaps` put in them.

### What is the best way to clear them?

In VBA the answer would be as simple as taking a `Worksheet` object then calling the method `WorksheetX.Pictures.Clear()`.  I tried a sort of direct C# translation of that:

```
Excel.Worksheet TempSheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(IndexVar);
TempSheet.Pictures.Clear();
```

But unfortunately `Worksheet.Pictures` has no available methods or properties.  I next thought I could find them in `Worksheet.OLEObjects`, but even going through that collection 1 by 1, I found that the images where not stored there.

I then tried to take a closer look at the MS list of [Excel.Worksheet methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet_methods%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) (and properties), and the only thing I could find that was close was [Excel.Worksheet.Pictures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.pictures%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), which contains the lovely note:

> This API supports the Visual Studio infrastructure and is not intended
>   to be used directly from your code.

So now I'm back at my original question, how do I get the images contained within a worksheet?  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

My current workaround is to can a VBA micro, but that is exceedingly cumbersome.  I'd rather handle it all in C# to avoid any VBA if possible.

If I have more than 1 picture in the sheet, I am able to run:

```
Excel.Worksheet TempSheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(IndexVar);
foreach (void XXX in TempSheet.Pictures) {
    if (XXX.Index > 1) {
        XXX.Delete();
    }
}
```

And that will leave 1 image behind (I guess it's 1 based not 0 based counting)

But if I just try:

```
Excel.Worksheet TempSheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(IndexVar);
foreach (void XXX in TempSheet.Pictures) {

        XXX.Delete();

}
```

Then it causes Excel to crash.

Comment: Might be one of those times where you add a reference to the VB code library just to use the VBA-type syntax!

Comment: @MacroMan Doesn't that cause a large performance drop?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not an user of VSTO, but it seems that you are left with one picture as you are deleting all pictures with index above 1.
I suggest to change this line:

```
if (XXX.Index > 1) {
```

to:

```
if (XXX.Index >= 1) {
```

Hopefully it will delete all now.

Comment: I tried that, and that essentially acts the same way is not declaring anything about the index. Which is to say Excel crashes, and attempt to restart. I haven't even figured out a way to wrap error handling around the crash that executes (it still crashes Excel.exe as a whole)

Comment: An ex-MS programmer suggested the crash came from removing all members of the Pictures collection without clearing it, but then when I got back to the code '.clear' wasn't a method

Answer (score -2):

First identify the picture count and delete.

The below line of code will help you to identify the count of pictures in the workseet.

WorkSheet.Pictures().Count

Comment: This answer is rather short. Could you please explain a little bit more and also give an extended example code.